# Office 2000 - Using folders as addressbook isn't working

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-outlook, office-2000

I've googled around, and I couldn't find any sensible answers. A lot of them talk about Office 2000 Corporate edition, but the problem is with

> Microsoft Outlook 2000 (9.0.0.2711)
> Alleen Internet e-mail ("Only Internet Email"?)

The fact that the installation is in Dutch isn't helping.

Anyhow.

The problem is that suddenly the Contacts folder can't be accessed from the "Namen Selecteren" ("Select Names"?) dialogue that you get when clicking on the "To" button when composing an e-mail. I've set the folder to be displayed as an e-mail address book:

[image: Dutch version of the "Contacts" folder properties window, "Addressbook" tab]

But it doesn't show when composing:

[image: Dutch version of the "Select Names" window, showing the missing addressbook]

It worked yesterday, and suddenly stopped working. The only suggestions I could find was with the corporate edition, something about a services, which doesn't apply here.

Answer (score 0):

I was using Outlook Address 2000 for years and liked its simplicity.

I started using Windows 7 and my address book was not available. Missing a `dll` file. I had Office 2000 on my computer and loaded Office 2013 with it. I did not like the complexity of Office 2013. The good news is that with them both on my computer, Office 2000 worked great. My old Address Book loaded on the computer, saving me a lot of typing. I did the same thing when I lost my computer and went to Windows 7-64 bit. Same results. You are using Outlook 2000 again. You have to use the 2000 icons.